# Memory allocation going from 0 to 200mb+ in just 3 secs.

Tags: android, xml

I am building a simple UI . I have set that activity as launcher activity by setting intent-filter in that activity .
In that activity I have just changed it's XML(everything is hard-coded in XML)  , nothing changed in Java class.

When I launch that app , memory increases very quickly . Here is the google doc for my XML:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sgH1Zvu4VtWhefIDIWcjOLw_pEw8qH9J_LYrX0I92VM/edit

here is the screenshot of my monitor : [image]

Please tell me the reason for this sudden hike in memory .

Comment: Post here the XML, don't link it from Google Drive

Comment: Beyond that, take a heap dump and determine where your memory is going.

Comment: To echo those comments, you probably have a large image in the xml file

Comment: @Fondesa answer was exceeding the word limit. That's why I pasted on Google Drive.

Comment: @Shmuel What do you mean by large image ? 
"Size" wise or "Resolution" wise .

Comment: Exceeded you word limit, how large is it?? Also, the drive file is not shared publicly.

Comment: It's pretty large . all of the things are hard coded as of now. 
And sorry for the drive. I have made it public now.

Comment: @Shmuel I have used only two images in the whole Layout. I have reduced their resolution from "1024*1024" to "48*48". 
The memory size is reduced to 160mb . 
but still it's a lot of memory that is being used by this activity .

Answer (score 1):

Your xml looks like you have a list of items that are scrolling. 
The correct way to implement this is to use a RecyclerView.

As you've seen, using a scroll view forces the entire view to be in memory at once and is killing your performance.

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html

Comment: Yeah I am familiar with those . But i just need to convert the Mock ups into XML, That's why I have hardcoded each and everything . 
I have to use scrollview to Make it Scrollable , if it is making a problem then what should be the substitute of the scrollView .

Comment: If you 'just want to create a mock up' and dont need to worry about performance, then dont change anything. If you want to code it correctly the switch over to a RecyclerView.

Comment: also, can you share a screen shot of the ui?